# How can I share a Windows 7 library with anonymous access without using a Homegroup?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, network-shares, file-sharing

The "homegroup" feature is useless, because it requires a password, and therefore doesn't support anonymous, no-hassle access to shares from devices such as my Sony Bravia TV and non-Windows7 machines.  So I turned off homegroup and reverted to the standard shared folders protocol.

I'd like to share my Music "Library", so I can play files from my TV through the Surround Sound System, but there seems to be no option to share a library folder other than through a homegroup.

I don't want to have to individually share the folders that belong to the library, because that would defeat the purposes of the library, which is to manage which folders are included in the library while also providing an easily accessible view of them all at once.

Does anyone know how to share a Windows 7 library without that useless homegroup feature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just SHARE a library. You would need to share the folders that belong to the library. Are there that many that it is that big of a pain to do once? I am not in front of my windows 7 machine for the next couple hours. I will look into it further when I am

Alternatively and the way I ended up going was:
If your television/media player support UPNP check out [TVERSITY](http://tversity.com/) it is free and it rocks!

Comment: I'll check out TVERSITY.  But yes, you can share the library as a whole when Homegroup is on.  When it's off, you can't... the sharing tab vanishes from the library's properties.

Comment: TVERSITY is the way to go! I had a similar issue with a server 2008 in my basement. Tversity is really simple to setup and manage as well it offers things like YouTube streaming as well as premium content if you want to buy the full version. I am not a spokesperson I just think it is great software. I did check out my Win 7 machine but I cannot share a library as I am part of a domain. I really would just share the individual folders. If you put all your television files in a Television folder and share it is it that much worse than not having it in a library?